# select element with selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-selectors, checkbox

i want to select a element with jQuery.

```
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox1</label></li>
         <ul class="list">
          <li>lorem</li>
          <li>lorem</li>
          <li>lorem</li>
        </ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox2</label></li>
         <ul class="list">
          <li>lorem</li>
          <li>lorem</li>
          <li><lorem/li>
        </ul>
 </ul>
```

I want to hide and show the list thats directly under the checkbox with 1 jQuery function.

```
 $(".list").hide();

$(".checkbox").click(function() {

    if ($(".checkbox").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("????").show('slow');
    }
    else
    { 
        $("????").hide('slow');
    }
});
```

The ???? needs to be a selector thats (only) selects the list under the checkbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, your HTML is invalid, as you cannot have elements between the `li` in a `ul`. Change your HTML to this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox1</label>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox2</label>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li><lorem</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Then you can use the cloest parent `li` as a context to find the related `ul`:

```
$(".list").hide();

$(".checkbox").click(function() {
    var $parentLi = $(this).closest("li");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("ul", $parentLi).show('slow');
    }
    else { 
        $("ul", $parentLi).hide('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

```
$(".checkbox").click(function() {

    if ($(".checkbox").is(":checked"))
    {
        $(this).next('ul').show('slow');
    }
    else
    { 
        $(this).next('ul').hide('slow');
    }
});
```

However as pointed out, your HTML is invalid, the child `<ul>`s should be inside `<li>`s themselves.

Also, depending on the initial visibility/state of the checkboxes, you can shorten the code by using `$(this).next('ul').toggle('slow');` instead of checking the check box checked status.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7WDJ/ a simple version of what you want. It selects the next `.list` element and toggles it when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse your structure quite easily with

```
$(this).parents('li').children('.list').show('slow');
```

There may be a more succint way of doing it if you read the jquery docs on selectors & traversing